# Install Windows 7 On MacBook (x) 2015

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I have just looked on MacRumours and found out that Apple have stopped support for installing Windows 7  with BootCamp on the 2015 MacBooks (Air and Pro) ([link](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/03/20/new-macbook-pro-air-no-windows-7-bootcamp/)). Since I am going to get the new 12" MacBook I am guessing that too doesn't support Windows 7 using bootcamp.

Since Apple are stopping the drivers for the 2015 models as well, is there still a way to install Windows 7 on the 2015 versions of the MacBook? (I sometimes need Windows 7 on my Mac for college)

**Edit**

Thank you for the replies.

I ended up getting the MacBook Pro since they didn't have any MacBooks in store. Since I have the MacBook Pro I can now run Windows 7 in a virtual machine (as suggested by you) because I do not have heat and performance issues.

Comment: You are taking this out of content. Apple stopped the support for the older version (advanced age-Windows 7) but it will support the newer Windows 8, that replaces its predecessor.

Comment: I know. I have also said I need to install Windows 7. I want/need to install 7 because I don't like 8 and my college uses 7.

Comment: Apple also no longer offers Mavericks on they site, as it has been replaced with Yosemite. (like it or not). You can not get new Apple devices with Mavericks even if you loved it. Sometimes you have to cut the umbilical cord and move on.

Comment: I have also said I need sometimes for college. It is not just because I like it. There may still be a way how to use Windows 7 on a 2015 MacBook.

Comment: I got it that you want the W7 but you can not obtain it "legally" from MS anyway. So where would you W7 copy come from ? If you go to MS web site they only offer W8 for download. "Microsoft ended sales for W7 in October 2013".

Comment: I have a Windows 7 Installer that I did get legally (got it for free using 'onthehub.com' because I get a student discount)

Comment: I'm just going to throw this out here since it hasn't been mentioned, in this thread yet anyway, if you absolutely do not need to have it running natively installed via Boot Camp you can still run Windows 7 in a virtual machine.  You can use the free VirtualBox if you don't want to pay for VMware Fusion or Parallels.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sill want to see if there are any alternatives since I'm not sure how the 12" MacBook will handle the VM. If I cannot run Windows 7 I may do Windows 10 (even it it is still in preview mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install unsupported operating systems such as Linux or older Windows versions by not using the bootcamp assistant.

Open disk utility and create a partition, format it FAT. 
Then reboot whole holding alt/option and boot from the install-disc (CD, DVD, USB drive, ...) and install as usual.

Now comes the tricky part. Since the OS is not officially supported by Apple your on your own regarding driver-install. You'll be able to just use the regular drivers from the vendors for things like audio and wifi, for apple specific drivers, you can use the drivers that are downloadable by boot camp assistant. They single drivers are usually easily accessible in the package, you just can't use the Install-Everything App that Apple bundles with them.

Alternatively, use virtualization is a good option.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Looks like I may not be able to use the force track pad at least not all. (haptic feed back for example). I will there for use win 10.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. New 2015 MBP, USB 3 drive `dd`'d with the Win7 x64 ISO. USB drive doesn't show up as an option in the boot loader.

Comment: This is not an option because Windows 7 doesn't support USB 3 natively and you can't install from USB.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who:

1. Have a 2015 model of MacBook and does NOT support Windows 7
2. Want to take advantage of the free Windows 10 before July 2016

Bootcamp supports Windows 10 now, so I just spoke with Microsoft and gave them my Windows 7 key... and they provided me a new Windows 10 key to use.

Just adding this to the post since I fond this in my search for resolution.

Comment: Privacy concerns? :) Why I stick with Apple. :)

Comment: I called Microsoft and they didn't provide me a key. It is not how it works, they said. They didn't help at all.

Comment: Check again... maybe with someone else at Microsoft. This was honestly my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use Disk utilities to setup the 2nd partition then run Bootup tool rEFIt (used it before to access Ubuntu, Windows and OS X installed as well on my macbook pro).

Run Windows setup when you bootup on the created partition.

Download a previous set of drivers (latest ones I guess) and don't forget to back your drive.

You can get previous drivers to install by downloading them from [this unofficial site](http://www.123myit.com/boot-camp-drivers/)

Comment: oops forgot to read the updated part of the main topic. I guess that solves it as well (I am using a Macbook Air - 2015)