# Installing Windows 7 on a MacBook Air, Early 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, startup, windows

**The issue:**
I have an issue with an MacBook Air that I need to install Windows 7 on. The problem is that this MacBook model [does not support Windows 7 in Boot Camp.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) So I thought that I should instead install Windows without Boot Camp on the Mac hard drive. The problem is that when I boot the Windows 7 installation disk by pressing "Alt" at start up and choosing "EFI Boot" the loading screen freezes at "Windows is loading files..." just before it should start up. Also, the second before it freezes some tiny colorful lines appear in the upper right corner of the screen.
The DVD that I am installing from is working good on other PCs and on an older MacBook Air.

I need to run Windows 7 on this one and visualization nor an another Windows version is not an option in this case.

**What else that I have tried:**
I have tried with installing Windows 10 and then using the setup.exe file on the DVD to install Windows 7 but it freezes at a black screen in the first restart of the installation process.
Also, I have tried with starting the installation DVD from [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) but that gives the same result as with the original Apple boot loader, where you press "Alt" at start up.
Contacting Apple support does not give any assistance on how to install Windows 7 as it is not supported any more and they do not know any technical reason to why it isn't possible.  An internet search for the issue probably gave more information then they provided in an hour on the phone.
In addition I have tried to boot the installer from both a external USB DVD reader and an USB flash drive.

**My questions is:**
Is there any technical reason to why Apple choose to not support Windows 7?
Is it possible to install Windows 7 in an another way?
Any other ideas or suggestions (that is not running a PC instead or using visualization or an another Windows version)?

EDIT:
Found [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183387/116161) answer that says it is possible to do but it is also the only answer that I found which says that it is possible.

Comment: Added information in the OP about an answer that said it is possible but that is not working for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I assume when you pressed the "Alt" key at startup, you only get the "EFI Boot" and the "Windows" boot is missing?

Comment: @DavidAnderson While using the built in boot loader I only get "EFI Boot". But when using rEFInd I see two Windows boot options, one fail immediately by saying that it can't boot while the other one freezes at "Windows is loading files..." As described in the OP.