# Macbook Pro 2015 - Install Windows 7 then upgrade to Windows 10 (Boot Camp)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro and an OEM license of windows 7.

I plan to install Windows 7 with these instructions provided by Kevin in this thread:
[Install Windows 7 On MacBook (x) 2015](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177696/install-windows-7-on-macbook-x-2015)

This will hopefully let me boot camp into Windows 7 with some limited functionality.

My question is, since Microsoft is giving free upgrades to Windows 10, can I upgrade my windows 7 license to windows 10 through boot camp utility? Since my Windows 7 installation didn't use boot camp utility, will there be compatibility issues from upgrading from windows 7 to windows 10?

Also, has anyone with a virtual machine been able to claim their free upgrade to windows 10? Not clear to me if you are ineligible for upgrade if you have an OEM windows.

Comment: Win is eligible for the free update if it show as genuine in My Computer/Properties. So long as that's OK, it doesn't seem to make any difference as to what the source of the Win install was. I've updated 2 hardware machines & a VM, with no issues. Not tried Bootcamp yet, as my machine doesn't officially support BC6

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party! However, this is essential for anyone else in the same boat -

If you install Windows 10 directly and update to version 1511, it'll accept Win7/8/8.1 product keys when you activate.

Answer (score 0):

I ran Windows 7 on a Virtual Box VM and managed to upgrade to Windows 10. There was an issue upgrading from the Windows 10 icon in the task bar. It said the display driver wasn't compatible, but it upgrades fine if you download the Windows 10 iso file and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp now supports Windows 10 direct from ISO. Instead of trying to convert from Windows 7 to 10 in order to get the free license... just call or chat with Microsoft technical support and explain the situation.

I just did this myself, and they gave me a new Windows 10 license key in exchange for a valid Windows 7 key. Worked perfectly.

Save yourself the headache and do the above... there is no way a 2015 MacBook is going to run W7 with Bootcamp.

I did this over chat with Microsoft Answer Desk: https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/contact/chat/30/